# Image denoising using Dual-Tree Complex Wavelet Transform (DT-CWT)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

So, I'm doing my final project that involves blood vessel extraction from a retina image, and I'm trying to denoise an image using DT-CWT (I have done the previous preprocessing steps according to [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3864789/)...). I am using the *"dddtree2"* MATLAB function and I got this messege:

> Error using dddtree2 (line 103)
>   Invalid argument value L.
>
> Error in prog_skripsi (line 28)
>       dtcplx = dddtree2('cplxdt',retEnhance,4,'dtf3');

The codes to my project are

```
retG = retImg(:,:,2);
retStretch = imadjust(retG, stretchlim(retG), []);
retHmf = hmf(retStretch,3);      % Using hybrid median filter to remove noise before enhancement

retOpen = imopen(retHmf, strel('disk',10));
retTH = retHmf - retOpen;                       % Making the top-hat of image
retClose = imclose(retHmf, strel('disk',10));
retBH = retClose - retHmf;                      % Making the bottom-hat of image
retEnhance = retTH + retHmf - retBH;            % Enhanced image

dtcplx = dddtree2('cplxdt',retEnhance,4,'dtf3');   % Using DT-CWT to remove enhanced image's noise 
dtcplx.cfs{1} = zeros(size(dtcplx.cfs{1}));
dtcplx.cfs{2} = zeros(size(dtcplx.cfs{2}));
dtcplx.cfs{3} = zeros(size(dtcplx.cfs{3}));
dtcplx.cfs{4} = zeros(size(dtcplx.cfs{4}));
retDTC = idddtree2(dtcplx);
```

Any help to resolve this problem? Or did I do something wrong? Much appreciate the help....

Comment: What are the dimensions of `retEnhance`?

Comment: @beaker, 'retEnhance' is 1152x1500 pixels wide (is uint8)

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/dddtree2.html#inputarg_level), "If L is the value of level, 2^L must divide both the row and column dimensions of x. " The column dimension of 1500 is not divisible by 2^4.